# How to connect to an H2 database

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I created a new Spring Boot application with Spring Initializr, and I included H2 and JPA.

I created a test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
class DemoApplicationTests {
    private final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Autowired
    DemoApplicationTests(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Test
    void queryTest() {
        entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager().createQuery("select 1 from dual").getFirstResult();
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No
> ParameterResolver registered for parameter
> [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory] in
> constructor
> [com.example.demo.DemoApplicationTests(javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory)].

Do you have any idea what I might have done wrong? Have I missed something?

Comment: For tests, you shouldn't use an `@AutoWired` constructor, but an `@AutoWired` field. The test is created by JUnit, not by Spring.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed it, but, unfortunately, I another error: 
Failed to load ApplicationContext ... 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available